# Python pgsql error printed double times

Tags: python

I have a strange "problem" with the python pgsql library.
In my code, where i handle the error and print it, happens that it prints it 2 times.

This is the code:

```
def pg_connect():
    con = None
    try:
        con = psycopg2.connect(database=odoo_array['DBName'], user=odoo_array['User'], password=odoo_array['Password'], host=odoo_array['Host'], port=odoo_array['Port'])
        cur = con.cursor()


    except psycopg2.DatabaseError, e:
        print "["+cur_date()+"] Error: "+str(e)
        sys.exit(1)

    finally:
        if con:
            return cur


def cur_date():
    date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime( "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" );
    return date
```

When there is an error with the connection, i want the output, and i get this:

```
 [2015-08-12 09:09:46] Error: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 65432?
 could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 65432?
```

Can't understand why i get the error 2 times?

Comment: I don't think this is the actual code because it will crash on `try:`.

Comment: I need more code snippet, e.g. what is `cur`,  what is after `try` etc.

Comment: You didnt understand the point.
after the try, there is the string about connections.

The problem is the handeling of errors. I want to get only one message about error, not two.

After the try: we have:
con = psycopg2.connect(database=odoo_array['DBName'], user=odoo_array['User'], password=odoo_array['Password'], host=odoo_array['Host'], port=odoo_array['Port'])
        cur = con.cursor()

Comment: @ADiEmme We did get the point, but the code you posted doesn't even work.. Where does the `cur_date()` come from?

Comment: I dont want to know why it crashes, i want only to know why it shows the error 2 times.

The cur_date is a function which returns the datetime.

Anyway, adding more code.